# How to maintain the session throughout all pages in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, session

Managed to change the theme programmatically by changing the CSS file using the following code.

```
css.Href = "App_Themes/bootstrap.min.css";
css.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
css.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
css.Attributes["media"] = "all";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(css);
```

Since i have to maintain the theme chosen i added a session to the above code which is equal to the dropdown list value selected. (Drop down list which the user selects the theme)

```
Session["theme"] = themeddlist.SelectedValue;
```

How can i maintain this session throughout other pages?

I tried the following code which equals it to the session that the user is logged in.

```
Session["theme"] = (String)Session["loggedUser"];
```

It does not maintain the session though.

Comment: ASP.NET applications maintain their session automatically, so that wouldn't be the problem.

Comment: It should maintain automatically... though  when I use server.transfer i do get problems donno why

Answer (score 0):

Check in your web.config if you changed the session timeout.
Also I would use cookies for user settings.

```
Session["theme"] = (String)Session["loggedUser"];
```

You don't need this cause a session is always bound to a specific computer/browser.